# Django background tasks not taking new code into account

Tags: django, cron, background-process

I am using django background tasks to run some code in background. My project has been deployed and I run the background tasks using cron. The problem is when I made changes to my code, the ones related to the background tasks are not taken into account. It seems the cron still using the old code.

This is my crontab

```
*/5 * * * * /home/.../venv/bin/python /home/.../manage.py process_tasks [duration 299]
```

I think i need to kill the cron command and allow the code to update before running it again.

Comment: you should re-run the cron command so it reloads the new code.

Comment: But that ought to be a new instance of manage.py process_tasks every 5 minutes.

Comment: what does `process_tasks` do? It's strange it wouldn't take the new code, when you run manage.py it has to run whatever code is currently deployed.

Comment: you should try to manually execute that command to see if it works. there is nothing to do with the crontab because it is just automating the manual execution every 5 secs.

Comment: What type of code change is not taken into account? Note that with django-background-tasks, the actual tasks scheduled are registered in the database. If you change the variables passed to your tasks or the schedule of the tasks, you need to re-register the tasks (and I think also remove the existing ones from the db). But if you just change the logic of the task function, the new code should be executed.

Comment: Also note that during 299s (duration), the tasks functions will not be updated, because it's loaded with one management task. So you have to wait up to 5 minutes to see any code changes.